# Creating a Textured 2D Sprite using Points in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am working on a smooth terrain generation algorithm in C# and using XNA to display the data.

I am making it so it creates a new point halfway between each point per iteration, at a random height between the two. This works OK, and I am getting the current result, randomly placed points.

[image: Current Result]

Now what I want to do is turn these points into a primitive (I think that is what it is) and display it like a mountain, obviously using a mountain texture. Example below (using different point data, made up in paint)

[image: Example Result]

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated, and look forward to your responses.

Thanks.

Twitchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw triangle strips alternating between the points in your primitive and the bottom of the screen with the same x coordinate as the point just before it, stepping along the bottom of the screen.

I am not familiar with drawing primitives in XNA (just openGL), but it should be similar.

You take your points, e.g.  A,B,C and D
to draw the strips. you would have your vertices ordered as;

```
vertex1= A  
vertex2 = point(A.x, 0)  
vertex3= B  
vertex4 = point(B.x, 0)  
vertex5= C  
vertex6 = point(C.x, 0)  
vertex7= D  
vertex8 = point(D.x, 0)
```

(I assume the bottom of the screen has a y coordinate of 0, it can be screen height or whatever y you choose)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Provide me an example?